# Python postgreSQL update not changing row but no error

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sql-update

Trying to execute an UPDATE statement on a Postgres 12 database.
SELECTs work fine.
db user has full read/write permissions.
Can't get Python to display/log any db errors.
Removed "TRY... EXCEPT" from the code below for easier readability.
The Python program flow is uninterrupted, as if the update worked.
But I check the database and the i_sec_level did not change to 5.

Relevant Python code:

```
db_conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host=t_host,
    port=t_port,
    dbname=t_dbname,
    user=t_user,
    password=t_pw,
    cursor_factory=DictCursor
    )
db_cursor = db_conn.cursor()

    q = ""
    q += "UPDATE tbl_users SET "
    q += " i_security_level = %(i_security_level)s"
    q += " WHERE "
    q += " id = %(id_user)s"
    vars = {
        'i_security_level': int(i_security_level),
        'id_user': int(id_user)
        }

db_cursor.execute(q,vars)
logging.debug(db_cursor.query)
db_conn.commit()
db_cursor.close()
db_conn.close()
```

Python log of db_cursor.query:

```
UPDATE tbl_users SET i_sec_level=5 WHERE id = 3
```

Postgres 12 log:

```
2020-09-22 14:33:47.112 CDT [640] LOG:  statement: UPDATE tbl_users SET i_sec_level=5 WHERE id = 3
2020-09-22 14:33:47.194 CDT [3284] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 1 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2020-09-22 14:33:47.195 CDT [3284] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 6 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2020-09-22 14:33:47.197 CDT [3284] DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 3 callbacks to make
2020-09-22 14:33:47.197 CDT [3284] DEBUG:  exit(0)
2020-09-22 14:33:47.199 CDT [3284] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2020-09-22 14:33:47.200 CDT [3284] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2020-09-22 14:33:47.201 CDT [3284] DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
2020-09-22 14:33:47.208 CDT [12120] DEBUG:  forked new backend, pid=8656 socket=5320
2020-09-22 14:33:47.209 CDT [12120] DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
2020-09-22 14:33:47.211 CDT [12120] DEBUG:  server process (PID 3284) exited with exit code 0
2020-09-22 14:33:47.220 CDT [12144] DEBUG:  snapshot of 1+0 running transaction ids (lsn 0/17DE0B0 oldest xid 596 latest complete 595 next xid 597)
2020-09-22 14:33:47.250 CDT [8656] DEBUG:  postgres child[8656]: starting with (
2020-09-22 14:33:47.261 CDT [8656] DEBUG:   postgres
2020-09-22 14:33:47.262 CDT [8656] DEBUG:  )
2020-09-22 14:33:47.262 CDT [8656] DEBUG:  InitPostgres
2020-09-22 14:33:47.263 CDT [8656] DEBUG:  my backend ID is 4
2020-09-22 14:33:47.265 CDT [8656] DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2020-09-22 14:33:47.267 CDT [8656] DEBUG:  received password packet
2020-09-22 14:33:47.272 CDT [8656] DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
```

Comment: Are you sure that the Python connection/code database and the database you are looking at to confirm `UPDATE` are the same?

Comment: Thanks. Yes. There is only one database on that server. The SELECTs I'm using use the same connection object, too.

Comment: Hmm, so much for the low hanging fruit. What are the values for `q` and `vars`? Pretty sure they are not at issue, still would be nice to see for completeness sake. What happens if you force an error in the query?

Comment: Edited initial question above to include q and vars.

Comment: So why are you using `AsIs` for `i_security_level`? Also are there any changes being made to `search_path`, so maybe a different `tbl_users` is being written to?

Comment: Great idea! I missed that. Fixed and tried again. No change. Editing original so others don't ask same question.

Comment: Seems like maybe the commit isn't working. I've been trying to figure out how to turn on auto-commit, hoping that may help. Or to see if I'm doing the commit wrong.

Comment: Also for completeness, psycopg2 version?

Comment: Latest psycopg2. Latest Python 3.8x. Latest Postgres 12.x.

Answer (score 1):

Woohoo! Adding

```
db_conn.autocommit=True
```

after instantiating the db_conn object did the trick!

Comment: Yeah, but that should not be required. I can `UPDATE` using the same procedure as in your original post. So something else is at work here. Probably still need to figure out what that is before it leads to other surprises.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a way to show what I get:

```
import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=production host=localhost user=postgres")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("update cell_per set cell_per = %s where category= 'HERB 3.5'", (19,))
con.commit()

# Postgres log at debug5

[unknown]-postgres-2020-09-22 17:23:17.237 PDT-0DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
[unknown]-postgres-2020-09-22 17:23:17.238 PDT-0LOG:  statement: update cell_per set cell_per = 19 where category= 'HERB 3.5'
--2020-09-22 17:23:18.223 PDT-0DEBUG:  snapshot of 1+0 running transaction ids (lsn 1/55611B50 oldest xid 133938 latest complete 133937 next xid 133939)
[unknown]-postgres-2020-09-22 17:23:18.246 PDT-133938DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: END; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 133938/1/1
```

This is with `psycopg2-binary==2.8.6` and `Postgres 12.3`. The change shows up in the database.